# Appending JsonFile (UrL) in array to display on application

Tags: alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to add my data from my Json file into the application.I want append the Authors name from the Json file into the empty array.
I have added all of the areas that needed to be added when i run the simulation i get an empty array. I need it display the Authors first name on the simulator.

Does anyone know what i need to do to my code to make it work?

My Code :

```
var AuthorGlobal = [String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var DisplayAuthor: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    DisplayAuthor.text="\(AuthorGlobal)"
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://178.62.83.50/newsletters.json")
        .responseJSON { response in
            //                print(response.request)  // original URL request
            //                print(response.response) // URL response
            //                print(response.data)     // server data
            //  print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let _ = response.result.value {
                // print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }

            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
            if let Author = json["NewsLetter"][0]["Author"].string {
                AuthorGlobal.append(Author)

            }
            if let LastName = json["NewsLetter"][0]["LastName"].string {
                print(LastName)
            }
            if let ArticleTitle = json["NewsLetter"][0]["ArticleTitle"].string {
                //Now you got your value
                print(ArticleTitle)
            }
            if let Author = json["NewsLetter"][1]["Author"].string {
                //Now you got your value
                print(Author)
            }
            if let LastName = json["NewsLetter"][1]["LastName"].string {
                //Now you got your value
                print(LastName)
            }
            if let ArticleTitle = json["NewsLetter"][1]["ArticleTitle"].string {
                //Now you got your value
                print ("Article Title: " + (ArticleTitle))
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you print your `json` object and paste here.

Comment: its too long to paste here?

Comment: You can share a link with JSON in it or paste relevant data in context here. I wanted to know the data hierarchy basically.

Comment: im so sorry. Here you go: http://178.62.83.50/newsletters.json

Answer (score 0):

I just tried by putting your `json` in my file system and loading it locally. Below is my code on Swift 2 and it all worked fine. You might want to check the JSON data coming correctly in your service call. Also, try to compare it line by line with my code to see if you missed out something. Its too late for me to call it a day so bear with me to not pointing out the exact root cause in your code!

```
var AuthorGlobal = [String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var DisplayAuthor: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//        DisplayAuthor.text="\(AuthorGlobal)"
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);

        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1", ofType: "json")
        var fileContents : String = ""

        do {
            fileContents = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        } catch (_) {

        }

        var json : Dictionary<String,Array<Dictionary<String,String>>> = Dictionary()

        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(fileContents.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, String>>>
        } catch (_) {

        }

        let array = json["NewsLetter"] as Array?

        if let author = array?[0]["Author"] {
            AuthorGlobal.append(author)
        }

        print(AuthorGlobal) // This prints - ["Tom"]

        if let LastName = array?[0]["LastName"] {
            print(LastName) // This prints - Holton
        }

        if let ArticleTitle = array?[0]["ArticleTitle"] {
            //Now you got your value
            print(ArticleTitle) // This prints - XcodeGhost: Apple suffers a major malware infection inside the iOS app store.
        }

        if let Author = array?[1]["Author"] {
            //Now you got your value
            print(Author) // This prints - Sam
        }

        if let LastName = array?[1]["LastName"] {
            //Now you got your value
            print(LastName) // This prints - Devaney
        }

        if let ArticleTitle = array?[1]["ArticleTitle"] {
            //Now you got your value
            print ("Article Title: " + (ArticleTitle)) // This prints - Article Title: Google is 2 Billion Lines of Code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, where you have added  "print (AuthorGlobal)" i want that to be displayed in the viewDidLoad. I have added a line of code there which is : DisplayAuthor.text="\(AuthorGlobal)" <<i want to display "Tom" in there

Comment: To do that you need to do like this --> displayAuthor.text = AuthorGlobal[0] because AuthorGlobal is an array.

Comment: i get an error! ->> thread 1: xc_bad_instruction (code= xc_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Surely you are doing something wrong. Please show your code.

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        DisplayAuthor.text = AuthorGlobal.[0]
    }

Comment: Thats wrong... It should be `DisplayAuthor.text = AuthorGlobal[0] `. Notice that you have an additional DOT "." after `AuthorGlobal `.

Comment: ^^ thats the only thing i have changed from what you saw when i asked the question

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        DisplayAuthor.text = AuthorGlobal[0] .
    }

added and the error that i get is : expected member name following "."

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your project. I can take a look and suggest you the fix.

Comment: Yes, i can but where can i share it, its to big to paste on here!